# Is there any far right president that improved a country?

Tags: president, history, ideology

I'm currently watching the french debates for the presidential election, and looking at Marine Le Pen (far right), I was wondering if there was any elected president considered far-right that improved the status of any country in the world.

Thinking about it, who comes to mind is Franco in Spain, Mussolini in Italy, Nicolae Ceausescu, etc.

But I might be biased in my thinking and lack enough knowledge to know that there are the same amount of far-right presidents that increased the quality of life in their countries.

So, is there any good far-right president that had a proven record of improving their country, or is it clear that having a far-right president is never good for any country?

By improving, what I try to mean is reducing the poverty, the number of unemployed people, or increasing the Gross Domestic Product. I precise "or" as it is not a requirement to have all of them that were improved, BUT, having one that was improved while the other was destroyed cannot be considered "improving". I hope this clarification is helpful.

(I'm talking about far-**right** here because it's the case in France right now, not because I believe - or try to insinuate - that far-left is better).

Comment: I think you will find a lot of different opinions on what is improving a country and what isn't. I can see answers that gives an example that others will say actually hurt the country.

Comment: Yeah. I wondered about defining what was the definition of "improving" as it might mean different things. I'll try to edit the question with some guidance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I see how this is clearly more subjective than what I was hoping. My initial aim was to find counter arguments against "far-right is destroying countries" which is the common thinking (I'm not taking any positions here, I like to think against the current to see if I'm not biased). Digging show that it's not as easy as I was hoping.

Comment: Are you interested in "notional improvement" (fairly straightforward to measure) or "real improvement" (much more difficult, arguably impossible, and subjective)? If a share portfolio returns 10% p.a. you might think the manager is doing a good job, until you realise that an index-linked fund would have returned 20% p.a.!

Comment: What's your definition of "far-right"?

Comment: Do autobahns count as improvement?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the GDP of Spain from 1850 to 2015.  The y-axis is a logarithmic scale. The period of Franco's dictatorship is marked as the grey rectangle.

By this measure, Spain made considerable economic progress from 1939 to 1975.   Of course so did the USA, France, Germany, Japan, and most other major economies. So you might not say this is the result of Franco, but merely the effect of worldwide economic growth following world war 2.  It is nearly impossible to say that a leader of any colour *improved* a country.  But it might be possible to say that in some ways a country improved, while that leader was in power.

The frame of reference in which you ask the question "A far-right leader that improved the country [...by...] increasing the Gross Domestic Product" without destroying other measures such as unemployment or poverty, is unanswerable, since it is impossible to unpick how much of the improvement was due to Franco, and how much was coincidental.  Nevertheless, in many ways, Spain improved in general economic wellbeing while Franco was in power.

[image]

Source of graph https://voxeu.org/article/spanish-economic-growth-long-run

Comment: Thank you for this, it is very interesting. The interesting point here is to wonder if the sum of all the other impact Franco had on his people was globally positive or not. That's why I did not want to take into consideration just one, independent, point.

Comment: You said " By improving, what I try to mean is [...]  increasing the Gross Domestic Product. I precise "or" as it is not a requirement to have all of them that were improved, BUT, having one that was improved while the other was destroyed cannot be considered "improving"" Now to make the question answerable you must accept that "better" is not measurable.  Here is the GDP. In 1975 the country was not destroyed by war, ravaged by revolution or racked by poverty.  Sure it wasn't better for everyone.  BUT here is a clear improvement. If you think something was destroyed please tell me.

Comment: So sorry if this is not the answer you want.  But if you want "global improvement" I would have to vote to close as "primarily opinion based".

Comment: Good answer but I wonder how the continuing upward trend **after** Franco compares to the slowing growth rates the rest of Europe faced in the 70s and 80s.  Looks to me like his departure facilitated a lot of growth, although EU membership no doubt was a huge factor.

Comment: Theres too much going on to ascribe anything on one person.  There was  The civil war, WW2, The post war recovery, massive industrialization, oil shocks in the 1970s, EU membership, a completely changed world trade structure.  So trying to pick out the effect of Franco on this is impossible and pointless.

Comment: It also begs the speculative & hypothetical question, what would have happened to Spain had Franco not won the civil war & been dictator (self assumed title of Caudillo) for as long as he was?

Answer (score 4):

You tried to make your question answerable by only looking at GDP or similar quantifiable economic markers. And James K has provided you with an answer including a graph that shows how Spain's economy grew during the period of Franco.

However, I'm going to have to give a counterpoint to show that *even* when resorting to quantifiable indicators the question may still remain barely answerable. Consider the graph I have created on [Our World in Data](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/maddison-data-gdp-per-capita-in-2011us-single-benchmark?time=1901..2000&country=SWE%7EESP) below, where I have compared Spain's GDP per capita to Sweden's. Unfortunately, the period of Franco's dictatorship is not highlighted. It began in 1939 which coincides with the small peak on Sweden's graph after the downward cliff on Spain's. It ended in 1975 with the death of Franco; this is where Sweden has a small plateau (1977 is the local minimum); to find it on Spain's graph, 1980 is another very tiny peak.

[image: GDP per capita from Our World in Data, shown for the years 1901 to 2000 in absolute numbers. Sourse: Maddison Project Database 2020.]

While yes, the economy did improve under Franco so did Sweden's economy without Franco. (Sweden has more of a dent caused by the Second World War while the corresponding dent in Spain's graph corresponds better to the Spanish Civil War.) Comparing the two graphs shows how Spain's economic growth matched Sweden's for the time period.

This is generally a problem for economic indicators. Politics has a surprisingly hard time at influencing them. The easiest way for politics to influence the economy is to start a war which will inevitably reduce output for some time. But not all crises are caused by war and the mere absence of war does not up the economy. In summary, unless there are very compelling reasons to attribute an economic development to a particular government that withhold academic scrutiny, I am inclined to chalk up all developments to external factors.